# Is my ER correct for my data?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, normalization, database-normalization

I want to create a database in Access. My data consists of quenstion, answers, department, revision Number, userID and date. There are two departments: A and B. Almost every question are the same for A and B, although the answers of A and B are not the same most of the time. It also shows which person changed which answer.

I tried to normalize it to 3NF

My data
[image]

My ER
[image]

Is my ER correct for my data? Im not sure about the blue line.

Answer (score 0):

Department and Question tables are fine, if the answers are open answers, the Answer table should be more like:

```
qID
depID
Answer
RevNr
UserID
Date
```

No point in having a Version table